# Application gets crashed with "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException"

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

App gets crashed while hitting web service. In Stacktrace showing following error;

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could
>   not open the database in read/write mode. at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:571)
>   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>   at bmn.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:72) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

But in my entire application I am not using any SQLite DB. I don't understand why its showing me this error.

Following is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="medimanage.corporate.mobile"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <permission
        android:name="corporate.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- for google maps-->
    <permission
        android:name="corporate.mobile.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="corporate.mobile.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".common.Utils.ApplicationLoader"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/medi_app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BrandedLaunch"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- All activities declarartion -->
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------------

        <activity
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.ExceptionReportActivity"
            android:process=":exceptionReporter"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />

        <service
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.ExceptionReportService"
            android:process=":exceptionReporter" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.targetUrl"
            android:value="url" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.dialogMessageHint"
            android:resource="@string/error_reporting_message_hint" />

        <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Key_value" />

        <!--[START] Google Analytics -->
        <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement -->
        <service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--[END] Google Analytics -->

        <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
        <service android:name=".FCM_Notification.MediFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
        <!-- [START firebase_id_service] -->
        <service android:name=".FCM_Notification.MediFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_id_service] -->
        <!-- SMS Reading for OTP -->
        <receiver android:name=".common.Utils.SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please provide any solution to handle this error.

Comment: you have to close database connection after read write operation

Comment: The manifest might not be the most useful thing. This error is likely a symptom. Have a look if there is another error around the same time which shows your application in the stack trace

Comment: But I am not using any DB connection through out my app

Comment: not using any database ?

Comment: Looks like a Firebase thing - `com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC`.

Comment: uninstall your app and try to run again.

Comment: @Nick Cardoso In full Stacktrace only showing "Could not open the database in read/write mode". But problem is I'm not using any DB connection in my application

Comment: check in DDMS your app have create any database ??

Comment: share your gradle file

Comment: share your activity code

Comment: for test case remove `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` then clean -rebuild and uninstall old app then run